# Show equality of an integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, inequality

Let $0\le K_N < N_{\gamma}\sim N$ and $0<n<N_{\gamma}$. We want to show as $N\to \infty$ we have

$$\int_{0}^{N_{\gamma}} \frac{1}{y}(1-(1-y/N_{\gamma})^{N_{\gamma}})(1-y/N_{\gamma})^{n-1}dy \sim log(N_\gamma)$$

Now my tutor says that we let $K_N \to \infty$ slowly and we divide the integrals in 3 regions $[0,K_N],[K_N,N_{\gamma}/logN]$ and $[N\gamma/logN,N\gamma]$. We have $(1-(1-y/N_{\gamma})^{N_{\gamma}}) \to 1$ outside the first integral and $(1-y/N_{\gamma})^{n-1} \to 1$ outside the third intervall so we conclude that the above is 
$$O(K_N) + \int_{K_N}^{N_{\gamma}/log N} \frac{1}{y}dy + O(loglogN).$$

Now I get that it is $\sim log(N_\gamma)$ and that $$\int_{K_N}^{N_\gamma/logN} \frac{1}{y}(1-(1-y/N_{\gamma})^{N_{\gamma}})(1-y/N_{\gamma})^{n-1}dy \le \int_{K_N}^{N_{\gamma}/log N} \frac{1}{y}dy$$ but I don't see why it should be equal. Why is it possible to ignore the terms and only write $$\int_{K_N}^{N_{\gamma}/log N} \frac{1}{y}dy$$
but don't change the upper limit to infinity?

Comment: Just guessing but, could be related to this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glasser%27s_master_theorem

Comment: I don't think I need a theorem. I rewrote my question, maybe it is clearer.